# How to make sure integrity and consistency of data is maintained by Spring Transaction?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-transactions

My transaction configuration is as follows, I am wondering if current configuration would maintain integrity and consistency of data while receiving concurrent requests. If the code is fine, in which cases concurrent requests affect integrity or consistency of data?

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/process", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processNameForm(@ModelAttribute("Form") Form form, Model model)
            throws Exception {
        System.err.println("Received form details:" + form);
        long id = this.formService.saveForm(form);
        model.addAttribute("id", id);

        return "result";
    }
```

**Service**

```
@Transactional
public long saveForm(Form form) throws CannotSaveFormException {
    System.err.println("in saveForm of service");
    return formRepository.saveForm(form);
}
```

**Repository**

```
@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public long saveForm(Form form) {
    return (Long) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(form);
```

**Configuration**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/Test" />
    <property name="username" value="jack" />
    <property name="password" value="jack" />
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
    depends-on="dataSource">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.test.model" />

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless your database tables are using a non-transactional engine, like MyISAM, I think you are doing alright. Concurrent requests won't affect the integrity or the consistency in your case.

Concurrent requests are pretty common with Servlet based applications. So, you'll need to go out of your way in order to break the integrity, consistency etc. For ex. you might change the the transaction isolation level to something like [READ_UNCOMMITTED](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Isolation.html#READ_UNCOMMITTED) in your `@Transactional` annotation (or in global config), which would allow a transaction to read uncommitted data from another transaction.

Another would be setting the propagation attribute in `@Transactional` to something like [NEVER](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#NEVER), or even the [SUPPORTS](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#SUPPORTS) where there is no pre-existing transaction.

Both of those cases look quite unlikely.

Another way would be to have your transaction related code somehow be dependent on mutable global/shared state. For ex. a global mutable instance in your service, DAO, or controller, which can be set through multiple requests. Again, I don't see that happening in your code. Shared mutable state is THE reason behind most of the concurrency issues. But the standard Spring practice, as far as I know, is to avoid it altogether. Things may be either mutable or shared, but not both and it will be okay. For ex. the code that mutates your instance inside the methods is safe from concurrency issues as it exists on the stack, and is not shared between threads.

Other than that, I think you are safe.

Comment: In which cases concurrent requests affect integrity or consistency of data?

Comment: @Jack I just updated the answer. TL;DR; version is: you would need to go out of your way to break the integrity, consistency etc.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, would you give me an example of shared and/or mutable datA?

Comment: @Jack talking about shared mutable state, and the related concurrency issues could be an entire answer on its own. Any simple example I can think of would be too naive and may not help with understanding the related concurrency issues. But the link [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp09238/) can serve as a good starting point. Plus, if you are inclined, you can try your hands on the [best concurrency book](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0321349601/), especially as it concerns java (but the concepts remain the same across languages).